# Minecraft API timestamp when an name can be taken

Tags: javascript, php, api, minecraft

I am trying to check out the following.

First step 1: I try and get the UUID of the selected name you wanna SNIPE.

```
public function api_call($username){
   $ch = curl_init();

   //Set other default cUrl settings
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://eu.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/" . $username);

   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "certificates/curl/cacert.pem");

   $response = curl_exec($ch);

   if($response) {
       $decoded = json_decode($response);
       $uuid = $decoded->uuid;
   }
   return $uuid;
```

This did work yesterday and somehow it doesn't resolve the UUID of the selected username anymore.

Did mojang update the API or am I just wrong?

The goal is that people can snipe a name at my service like "bat" which is $username ^above.

https://nl.namemc.com/s?Bat

Bat is available soon, I wanna make something which checks when it is available so my sniper can take it on the second.

Steps what you need to do.

1. Someone fills in the form and gives name Bat.
2. Script checks the name Bat and the name the guy changed it to from Bat.
3. Grabs UUID of Bat with this https://eu.mc-api.net/v3/uuid/ilustody (ilustody) is the name who had Bat. UUID is = ad374c96e8fb4cd097898b9ac3baf2d7
4. Now you fill in the UUID here like 
   "(can't fill in https because dont have 10 reputation) https//api.mojang.com/user/profiles/" . $UUID . "/names");

   ```
   $UUID = ad374c96e8fb4cd097898b9ac3baf2d7;
   if($response) {
       $decoded = json_decode($response);
       $uuid = $decoded->uuid;
   }
   return $uuid;
   ```

And then he takes this out of the new API : "changedToAt":1423045122000}
then make script which adds javascript timestamp of 3196800000 <37 days

and then it returns a date when it is available exactly.

I  hope someone can help me I am really desperate.

Comment: `mc-api.net` isn't the official mojang API.  The official API is hosted on `api.mojang.com` and documented [here](http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API).

Comment: I know it is, could you reply to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923876/mojang-api-retrieve-latest-uuid-of-username?noredirect=1#comment57774174_34923876

Comment: I will, give me some time though.  I'm looking into it.

Comment: Alright thanks alot, can I contact you through anything mate? Skype or anything else?