# Mojang API - Retrieve latest UUID of username

Tags: php, api, curl, minecraft

I am currently trying to make an API call using cURL with PHP to retrieve the UUID of the **latest** user that has used a username.

Using the [Mojang API](http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API):

> Username -> UUID at time

When making an API call for example: the user '*Chocolates*' (Which has been used by four users according to [NameMC](https://namemc.com/s?Chocolates)) I get the UUID of the first ever user using that name.

**Code:**

```
public function api_Changedto($uuid, $username)
   {
      $ch = curl_init();

      //Set other default cUrl settings
      curl_setopt(        $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,   1);
      curl_setopt(        $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,           0);
      curl_setopt(        $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,   1);
      curl_setopt(        $ch, CURLOPT_POST,         0);
      curl_setopt(        $ch, CURLOPT_URL,          "https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/" . $uuid . "/names");

      curl_setopt(        $ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,     "certificates/curl/cacert.pem");

      $response = curl_exec($ch);

      if($response) {
         $decoded = json_decode($response);

         $match = false;

         foreach ($decoded as $userInfo){

            if($match){

               $changedTo = ($userInfo->changedToAt + 3196800000) / 1000; 
               break;

            }else{
               if(strtolower($username) == strtolower($userInfo->name)){
                  $match = true;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      return $changedTo;
   }
```

> ?at=0 can be used to get the UUID of the original user of that
>   username

Is there a workaround to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It seems that curl is using a cache.
You should look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15493769/is-there-a-way-to-tell-curl-to-not-use-cache

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't really make sense. How can that fix the issue that I get the first given UUID?

Comment: To clarify, when you say 'latest' you mean 'most recent', right? But also, if nobody is using the name right now, find the _last_ person who used the name?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean @pockechu22 could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the API you are searching for: 
`https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/<username>`

A `GET` request to this URL should tell you the UUID of the account currently using the specified username, or HTTP status code 204 if the name isn't used by anybody at this time.

To get the latest user in this case, you should make another request to that URL, but this time you would add `?at=<currentUnixTimestampInSeconds - 30 days>` as query string to the request.

If this gives you HTTP 204 again, try a timestamp 60 days ago, and so on. Repeat this until you got the UUID or the timestamp is lower than 1423008000, because thats when name changing was enabled.